# Print order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why this happens? The console output is unordered in relation of my code. Does it have to do with memory?

```py
mylist = [0, 1, 2]

def game_intro():
    print("Hello! Welcome to the game!\n")
    print(f"Here is the current list:\n{mylist}")

def input_check():
    guess = input("Pick a number to replace: ")

game_intro()
guess = input_check()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your editor does this. It brings the input prompt to the top. It doesn't have anything to do with memory or...! Try running it in a terminal and you see the order is as expected

Comment: Also, function `input_check` does not return anything.

Comment: Which program are you using to show this output?